# redirect java log into a jsf component (in real time as netbeans or eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, jsf-2

I have a java method which is too long to wait. I want to have regular feedback into a jsf graphic component as inputTextarea

Here is what I thought : "redirect java console into a graphic component to give to the admin a regular clear idea of the execution of the method". He really need it!

But I am blocked.

********My inputTextarea is refreshed only at the end of the method.

How can I refresh it in real time ? (wheather the method is ended or not)

Comment: have you tried `threads` ? can you show part of your code where you have the issue?

Comment: I hava tried <p:poll> from Primefaces. But no effect.

Comment: I have also tried threads. But the facts is that I want my method render asynchronous responses before the end of the execution. Threads modifies variables but do not make asynchronous response. Please, what is your opinion ? I want to display console in real time in a jsf components.

Comment: check [jsf ajax progress bar](http://www.javabeat.net/jsf-2-ajax-progress/)

Answer (score 0):

To be answered properly, the question needs to be divided in two problem :

1- **redirect the java log in the jsf components**

2- **display this jsf component in real time**

ok. If we agree on this subdivision of the problem, we can reign.

**I- redirect java console log in a jsf components**

For this exemple I choose `<h:ouputText />`.

To redirect the java console log in the component, you have to write your own **OutputStream**. Exemple :

```
package stream;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import bean.managedBean.NBT;

public class StringOutputStream extends OutputStream implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public StringOutputStream() {

    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b)  {
        NBT.appendConsole(String.valueOf((char)b));
    }

}
```

**NBT is the managed bean who handle the jsf page.**

So we have something like this :

```
 @SessionScoped
    @ManagedBean(name = "Nbt")
    public class NBT implements Serializable{

    private static String log = ""; // The property linked to my <h:outputText /> 
//ex : <h:outputText id="logger" value="#{Nbt.log}" />

        public String getLog() {
            return log;
        }

        public void setLog(String log) {
            NBT.log = log;
        }

    public static String getConsole() {
            return log;
        }

        public static void appendConsole(String s) {
            log += s;
        }

    }
```

OK. We are together. But how will it work ? Source code :

```
PrintStream pstream = new PrintStream(new StringOutputStream(), true);
System.setOut(pstream);
System.setErr(pstream);
```

Details : PrintStream(yourOutputStream, true to "refresh automatically")
So when you will do : **System.out.println("AB C");**, **the text will not be print in the natural console** but it will be display in the `<h:outputText />`. here is what will happen in concrete terms :

```
yourStringOutputString.write('A');
yourStringOutputString.write('B');
yourStringOutputString.write(' ');
yourStringOutputString.write('C');
```

so you will do many `appendConsole` for all write method which will update `log` value; For each character of the text to display, the write method will be called. And you will have the result in your jsf component.

OK. The first problem is resolved.

**II- refresh jsf component in real time**

It is simple. Many ways could do that. But for me this is the most simple. Source code :

```
<h:outputText id="log" value="#{Nbt.log}" styleClass="thattext" />
<p:poll id="pollid" interval="2"
    update="log" widgetVar="poll"
    async="true" immediate="true" />
```

Your component will be upgraded every 2 seconds. 'async' attribute will make it **asynchronous**. neglect **immediate** attribute.

So this is the answer to my question which was : **How to redirect java log in a jsf component in real time ?**

It works for me. I see my console in my `<h:outputText />`.

Thanks !