# Show console output to UI in java

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, primefaces

Hi I have web application build in java using prime faces and spring.

I have one process in which I am printing some values on Console using `System.Out.println()`. Is there any way so that I can show these message on UI.

I have used primefaces log, terminal but it is only showing UI level rendering but I want Java output. The same way that are printing in Tomcat log.

I am using JSF 2 and prime faces 6.

Comment: Is there any way so that i can achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to output messages to the UI, explore something like [PrimeFaces Showcase: Growl](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml) or [PrimeFaces Showcase: Messages](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml). The showcase gives you some worked examples.

If it's just debug statements, you might be better off writing to a log file using something like the `@Slf4j` annoatation of [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/). It gives you the standard logging statements such as:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j
@Slf4j
public class SomeClass {
 ...
    log.debug("Some debug statement");
}
```

See [Introduction to Project Lombok](http://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-project-lombok) for more details.

Comment: Thanks For your reply Growl and messages show output after completion of process i want to show same as console

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795180/redirect-java-log-into-a-jsf-component-in-real-time-as-netbeans-or-eclipse?